# how can i upload the blob in azure using the shared access signature using PHP?

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using the azure php SDK and I have the SAS signature which I get from the application now how can I upload the file to the blob using the SAS( Shared Access Signature).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an SAS token, and if it has the write permission to blob in your Azure Storage Account, you can leverage the SAS token to upload your files directly to Azure Storage without Azure Storage SDK for PHP.

I assume that you have the correct SAS query string with signature, which should be similar with:
`?sv=2015-04-05&ss=bt&srt=sco&sp=w&st=2016-09-01T01%3A54%3A00Z&se=2016-09-02T01%3A54%3A00Z&sig=AQ%2F1yL8bt0AQzoYwtQmTUR6UKkJPC4PXg%2BxysdlkMoE%3D`

Then you leverage `cUrl` to create REST API request to Azure Storage to upload your file,

```
$sas= '?sv=2015-04-05&ss=bt&srt=sco&sp=rwl&st=2016-09-01T01%3A54%3A00Z&se=2016-09-02T01%3A54%3A00Z&sig=To%2BITizcZWTgr4I6o9BI%2Bdv34CBkuhV5%2BSEQXnaJr%2B0%3D';

$endpoint = 'https://<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net';
$container = 'test';
$blob = 'test.png';
$url = $endpoint.'/'.$container.'/'.$blob.$sas;

$uploadfile ="test.PNG";
$content = file_get_contents($uploadfile);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob','Content-Length: ' . strlen($content)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx for more details about the REST APIs for putting blobs to Azure Storage.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Liu - MSFT I am looking for this next time i will ask question with full detail .. and thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Our [PHP tutorial for blobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs/#set-up-an-azure-storage-connection) shows how to create a connection string and then upload a blob.

You can use the SAS as the credentials for your connection string. The connection string format is (line breaks included for readability only):

```
BlobEndpoint=myBlobEndpoint;
QueueEndpoint=myQueueEndpoint;
TableEndpoint=myTableEndpoint;
FileEndpoint=myFileEndpoint;
SharedAccessSignature=sasToken
```

Please see [Create a connection string using a shared access signature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-configure-connection-string/#create-a-connection-string-using-a-shared-access-signature) for more information and examples.

Comment: Can you provide the specific syntax? I've tried doing BlobEndpoint=[myendpoint];SharedAccessSignature=[my SAS token] and get an error "The setting key 'SharedAccessSignature' is not found in the expected configuration setting keys: UseDevelopmentStorage DevelopmentStorageProxyUri DefaultEndpointsProtocol AccountName AccountKey BlobEndpoint QueueEndpoint TableEndpoint in vendor/microsoft/azure-storage/src/Common/Internal/ServiceSettings.php"