# Upload File To Azure Storage Using Shared access signature using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, azure

I already generate the SAS url refered to this tutorial https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/05/12/generating-shared-access-signaturesas-on-azure-blob-using-php/

But i don't know how to use it in laravel,
I already try this answer in php [how can i upload the blob in azure using the shared access signature using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241302/how-can-i-upload-the-blob-in-azure-using-the-shared-access-signature-using-php)

But when i upload the file, suddenly the laravel server stop working.
this is sample of my url that i already generate

```
https://<myaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<mycontainer>/sample.jpg?se=2019-06-22&sr=b&sp=r&sig=hFMXU0%2BASHkHqxdpLd3695z9U3Koc9hEzI3%2Bfw5UmWQ%3D&sv=2018-03-28
```

Any help would be appreciate !
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SAS url just have the read permission, which is `sp=r` in your sample. If you want to upload the file, it should have the write permission `sp=w`.

For more details about SAS portion, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#service-sas-uri-example).

Comment: I tried it but it gives error CORS No Access Control Allow Origin, how can i overcome this?

Comment: @JoshParinussa Have you set the CORS rules in your storage account in the portal ->`CORS`? more details see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing--CORS--Support-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN).